# Can I do an internship in France on a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, study

I have been selected for a 2 month internship in a French laboratory. They will not pay me any money as stipend but rather they will reimburse my staying expenses. Can I apply for a tourist visa in this case instead of a student visa?

Comment: For how long is the internship?

Comment: It is 2 months long, from May to July.

Comment: I cannot work on a tourist VISA so they cannot pay me money as a stipend for the internship. But they will sponsor my lodging and food expenses which is mentioned in the offer letter that I received from my host laboratory.

Comment: What is the purpose of this internship? Is it part of studies?

Comment: Yes, the internship is related to my academic curriculum.

Comment: Housing and food are payments just not cash payments.

Comment: I don't think so, but you should ask the lab. Most research institutions have someone who knows how to get visas for the many foreign visitors that they get, whether it's for a short visit, an internship, a full academic year of study or teaching.

Comment: Housing and food is generally considered reimbursement, not payments, so I'm not sure. FWIW, it's usually permissible to travel on a "tourist" visa for business trips where all costs are bore by the company visited.

Comment: Yes, they are paying for my housing and my estimated food expenses will be reimbursed at the end of my stay.

Answer (score 3):

[You need a visa to complete an internship in France.](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/student-trainee) The visa you need depends on the duration of the internship. In your case, [you need a short term visa](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/short-stay-visa) since your internship lasts less that 90 days:

> ### Short-stay visa
>
> This type of visa is generally issued for tourism, business trips or family visits.
>
> It is also issued to persons entering to France to take part in short training programmes, internships, conferences and corporate meetings, or to engage in remunerated activities (whatever the form), not exceeding 90 days.

In addition [you need to be enrolled in education and must draft a written agreement with the host company or institution](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/student-trainee):

> ### The conditions
>
> Your project must be part of a training course organised in your country of residence (school curriculum, university degree or qualification) or an EU cooperation programme or an intergovernmental scheme in the fields of education, training, youth or culture.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Your supporting documentation
>
> In addition to the supporting documentation related to your personal situation as indicated in the visa wizard, you must include the [training agreement (pdf - in French only)](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/documents/66002/17040249/Convention+de+stage+%C3%A9tudiants.pdf/388a7ebe-dfb0-708f-07bd-fcd4913646bf) concluded between yourself, the training establishment and the host company in France.

Finally, note that [if the internship lasts longer than two months you are legally entitled to a compensation](https://www.net-iris.fr/indices-taux/paye/54-stage-gratification-stagiaire-remuneration-minimum):

> Tout stage d'une durée supérieure à 2 mois consécutifs ou, au cours d'une même année scolaire ou universitaire à 2 mois consécutifs ou non, donne lieu au versement d'une gratification. Le stagiaire en entreprise perçoit obligatoirement cette "indemnisation" à partir de la 309ème heure incluse.